# Comparing two large files

Tags: python, algorithm, bash, grep, large-files

I need to write a program that will write to a file the difference between two files.
The program has to loop through a 600 MB file with over 13.464.448 lines, check if a grep returns true on another file and then write the result onto another file.
I wrote a quick test with about 1.000.000 records and it took over an hour, so i'm guessing this approach could take 9+ hours.

Do you have any recommendations on how to make this faster? Any particular language i should use? I was planning on doing it in bash or python.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**[EDIT 1]:** Sorry, when i say difference between two files i did not mean a diff. The result file is in a different format.

The logic is a bit like this:

File A has 297.599 lines
File B has over 13 million lines

I pick the current line being read from FILE A, grep it on FILE B, and if the line is present in File B i will write it to the result file. By the way, File A and File B have different formats. Result file will have the format of File A.

**[EDIT 2]:** I was asked at work to create a bash solution ideally so that we don't have to install python on all the machines this has to run on.

This is my curent implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

LAST_TTP=`ls -ltr TTP_*.txt | tail -1 | awk '{ print $9 }'`
LAST_EXP=`ls -ltr *.SSMT | tail -1 | awk '{ print $9 }'`

while read -r line; do
   MATCH="$(grep $line $LAST_EXP)"
   echo "line: $line, match: $MATCH"

   # if not empty
   if [ ! -z "$MATCH" ]
   then
      echo $MATCH >> result
   fi

done < $LAST_TTP
```

This bash approach is taking over 10 hours to complete. Do you have any suggestions on how to make it more efficient in bash?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Maybe if you showed some code we could help optimizing it.

Comment: I don't quite get what you trying to achieve, but if your description is correct it would be improved if you'd sort these files

Comment: When you say difference... do you mean line by line? What I mean is, let say you have some line A on line number 100 and in the second file you have line B on line number 200. That does count as the same or different? Cuz if they are different just use the command diff

Comment: We can't tell you how to make it faster if we don't know what your desired output looks like.

Comment: @Flo: i updated the description explaining the logic a bit

Comment: It sounds like you're currently looping over each line of the second file for each line of the first - that's an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: Look into sorting the lines and the comparing them in order. It will slow down your algo to nlogn

Comment: If a line in File B matches one of the lines in File A, would you expect it to match another line in File A as well? If not, you could at least reduce the search space by removing matched lines from (your temp store of) File B as you went along.

Comment: please try the solutions that use join or comm. They should be nlogn

Answer (score 9):

You're probably looking in a list instead of a set, leading to an O(n²) performance. Try:

```
with open('b') as b:
  blines = set(b)
with open('a') as a:
  with open('result', 'w') as result:
    for line in a:
      if line not in blines:
        result.write(line)
```

Assuming uniformly long (and not overly long lines), the performance of this implementation is in `O(|A| + |B|)` (amortized, due to [Python's `set` being extremely fast](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set)). The memory demand is in `O(|B|)`, but with a factor significantly greater than 1.

If the order of lines in the output does not matter, you can also sort both files and then compare them line-by-line. This will have a performance in the order of `O(|A| log |A| + B log |B|)`. The memory demand will be in `O(|A|+|B|)`, or more precisely, `|A|` + `|B|`.

Comment: I think for `print(line)` your meant `result.write(line)`, correct?

Comment: Given the asymmetric sizes of the files, I think your answer is better than mine.

Comment: @MarkRansom Updated the answer with a crude analysis. While the set version seems to be at least as good as the sorting one in theory, in practice sorting (your solution) may better if there is significant memory pressure. This doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @phihag, How to display the count of `result.write(line)`?  I mean the number of lines going to be write in the result.

Comment: @MAK You can simply count up a variable on every line you write. If writing the result is very slow and you want to show the line count beforehand, use a list comprehension like `lines_to_write = [l for l in a if l not in blines]`, and write `lines_to_write` to the result file.

Comment: @phihag, Okay. But I want to insert the data in the result file and the count should be display in the prompt `>` by saying `count of lines difference` after program runs successfully.

Comment: @phihag, I did it by adding extra `with for a` and `with for b` to assign values to `list` `lines_to_write`.

Answer (score 4):

Sort each of the input files. Now read one line from each. If one line compares less than the other, output it as a difference and read the next line from that file. If both lines compare equal, read the next line from both files. If you read to the end of one file, all the lines in the other file are differences.

This is an O(n log n) algorithm as opposed to the O(n^2) algorithm you started with.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation seems to do:

```
grep --fixed-strings --file=file_B file_A > result_file
```

But both @phihag's and @mark Ronsam's answers are better solutions.

Also, if you wish to use the heavy guns, your solution is a good candidate for map-reduce frameworks such as hadoop.

Answer (score 2):

The join command also does what you want. join requires both files to be sorted up front. The option -v prints a line for each unpairable  line.

So you will want something like

join -v 1 sortedfile1 sortedfile2

(you will need to set the join options according to your file format, see manpage of join)

The below example joins the files test1.txt and test2.txt using the second resp. first field for the join. Assuming the files were sorted upfront using the sort command.
The -v 1 option only outputs the lines of test1.txt could not be joined.

```
>cat test1.txt
a 1 2
b 2 3

> cat test2.txt
1 x
4 x

> join -v 1  -1 2  -2 1  test1.txt test2.txt
2 b 3

> join -v 1 -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 test1.txt test2.txt
b 2 3
```

sort and join both work fine with large files.

Comment: ... by default, join puts the join columns in the front when outputting the lines. Using -o 1.1 1.2 1.3 you can keep the intended ordering from test1.txt.

Answer (score 2):

You can speed up your script slightly by stopping the `grep` when it finds the first match if that's appropriate for your needs.

If your `grep` supports it use `grep -m 1`.

Your problem is that you're spawning `grep` almost 300,000 times and it's reading over 13,000,000 lines each time.

Stopping `grep` at the first match will help a little, but the overhead of all those execs is a big factor as well. An implementation in Python will eliminate this issue.

As for choosing the files in your script, please see [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) and [Parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the comm command.  It should be faster than grep because it will work with sorted data while grep will always do a linear search

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use awk:

`awk 'NR==FNR { arrA[$0]; next } $0 in arrA' file_A file_B > result`

The order of files (... file_A file_B) in the command line is very important.

Comment: that's not doing anything for me, result file is blank

Comment: It works fine with my sample files:
<code>$ cat file_A
aaa
bb
fff

$ cat file_B
bb
ccc
ddd
aaa
eee

# Display records of file_B that are found in file_A:

$ awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$0]; next } $0 in arr' file_A file_B
bb
aaa

# Or the other way around:

$ awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$0]; next } $0 in arr' file_B file_A
aaa
bb</code>