# Python : Compare two large files

Tags: python, large-data, large-files

This is follow up question to [Compare two large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801760/comparing-two-large-files/10801819?noredirect=1#comment88476567_10801819) which is answerd by [phihag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35070/phihag)

I want to display the count of lines which are different after comparing two files. Want to display if after program completion as a message by saying **count of lines are in difference**.

**My try**:

```
with open(file2) as b:
  blines = set(b)
with open(file1) as a:
  with open(file3, 'w') as result:
    for line in a:
      if line not in blines:
        result.write(line)

lines_to_write = []
with open(file2) as b:
  blines = set(b)
with open(file1) as a:
  lines_to_write = [l for l in a if l not in blines]

print('count of lines are in difference:', len(lines_to_write))
```

Comment: To clarify, if you were given `"1\n2\n3\n"` and `"1\n1\n2\n",` the result should be 1?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq, Yes exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can load everything into memory, you can perform the following operations on sets:

```
union = set(alines).union(blines)
intersection = set(alines).intersection(blines)
unique = union - intersection
```

**EDIT:** Even simpler (and faster) is:

```
set(alines).symmetric_difference(blines)
```

Comment: Two issues: OP said the files are large and your approach compares '1\n2\n' and '2\n1\n' equal. (The second part might actually be correct if I misunderstood OP and the order of lines is irrelevant.)

Comment: I just edited my comment, this might be what OP wants, but I thought he wanted to compare corresponding lines. Let's wait for clarification!

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq, Almost done! The order of lines are missing and want to store it into third file and display a message the count of lines are different on prompt (**NOT IN OUTPUT FILE**) after program completion, as per your first comment the count will be `1`.

Comment: @MAK please don't change the requirements of your question after somebody has answered you. That makes people who want to help you pull their hair out. You said you wanted to count the lines, nothing more. if you have a new question, compose a new question.

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: This answer assumes you want to compare corresponding lines from the two files. If that's not what you want, ignore this answer. I'll leave it here for future readers.

---

If you just want the count of the lines, avoid creating large lists. Files are memory efficient iterators, and your task does not require more memory than is needed to look at two lines at once.

Demo (with two fake files)

```
>>> fake_file_1 = '''1
... 2
... 3'''.splitlines()
>>> 
>>> fake_file_2 = '''1
... 1
... 3
... 4'''.splitlines()
```

I am assuming that you want the answer `2` here, because the second lines differ and `fake_file_2` has an additional fourth line.

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest # izip_longest in Python2
>>> sum(1 for line1, line2 in zip_longest(fake_file_1, fake_file_2, fillvalue=float('nan')) 
...     if line1 != line2)
2
```

`zip_longest` works like `zip` and will yield pairs of corresponding lines from the two files. In addition, if one file is longer, the fillvalue `float('nan')` is inserted, which always compares unequal to anything (of course, you could just use any other dummy value like `0`, but I like it this way).

Instead of the fake files, just use the handles of your actual opened files.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a solution based on pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

**1. Create two pandas dataframes**

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(filepath_1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(filepath_2)
```

**2. For the case that your sentences contain any potential delimiters, join all columns to one**

```
df1 = df1.astype(str).apply(''.join)
df2 = df2.astype(str).apply(''.join)
```

**3. Concat both frames to one**

```
frames = [df1, df2]
df_merged = pd.concat(frames)
```

**4. Drop both copies of all duplicates**

```
df_unique = df_merged.drop_duplicates(keep = False)
```

**5. Count and print result**

```
print('count of lines are in difference:', len(df_unique))
```